# Does the work done in constructor account for time complexity of a method?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Below is the code to find "all" anagrams of input string. The bulk of the work is done in constructor, and the method by itself does little.

```
public class AllAnagramFInd {

    private final Map<String, String> dictionary;
    private Map<String, List<String>> anagramMap;

    public AllAnagramFInd(Map<String, String> dictionary) {
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
        anagramMap = new HashMap<>();
        createAnagramSignatures();
    }

    private void createAnagramSignatures() {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : dictionary.entrySet()) {
            String string = entry.getKey();
            String signature = getSignature(string);      
            if (anagramMap.containsKey(signature)) {
                anagramMap.get(signature).add(string);
            } else {
                List<String> anagrams = new ArrayList<>();
                anagrams.add(string);
                anagramMap.put(signature, anagrams);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getSignature(String str) {
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();      // returns a new arrayby Array.copy
        Arrays.sort(ch);    
        String sortedString = new String(ch);   // createa a new string object by Array.copy
        return sortedString;
    }

    public List<String> getAnagram(String str) {
        String signature = getSignature(str);
        if (anagramMap.containsKey(signature)) {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(anagramMap.get(signature));
        }
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
}
```

Here the constructor complexity is O(m * nlogn) where m is number of words in the dictionary and n is the max length of each word.

The method `getAnagram` itself has time complexity of O(n log n) where n is the maximum length of characters.

So what is the complexity of my algorithm ? Does constructor play a role in accounting for complexity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if you consider the complexity of the whole process or algorithm or just the complexity of every method separately. To me both approaches are valid:

Complexity of getAnagram -> O(n log n)

Complexity of createAnagramSignatures -> O(m * nlogn)

or

Complexity of the whole process or algorithm -> O(n log n) + O(m * nlogn) = O(m * nlogn)